# Simultaneous access SQLITE JAVA SERVICE / CordovaJS APP errors

Tags: java, sqlite, cordova

Aloa

I am trying to make an app (Android to begin, and then IOS) that one side (JAVA) executes SQL statements on a database stored on the phone (imported once from the www folder and using SQLiteOpenHelper ..) in java from a background service starting at the boot. No worries on that side.

On the other hand (CordovaJS) I check / update the same database from the same application, but in the GUI (webview) via the cordova Cordova-storage-sqlite plugin. No worries either on that side ...

But when JAVA and CordovaJS try to use the database at the same time, the app crash sometimes...

How can I do to access to the base of both sides simultaneously?
Otherwise what would be the best solution:

1. Create two separate databases with the same information that I would need to synchronize regularly between JAVA and CordovaJS in the two ways? Synchronization can possibly lead to the same problem of dual access ...
2. Create two bases, and communicate via flat files containing JSON data ...
3. Not to use databases and move only by flat files in JSON?
4. Any other ideas?

I'd rather largely retain only one database ...
Thank you in advance for review

PS: Sorry for my English, I'm French :(

EDIT:
Here is one of the errors occurs: W/SQLiteConnectionPool﹕ A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+data+com_app+databases+db.db' was leaked! Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

An other error seems like `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: error code 5: database is locked`

Comment: "the app crash sometimes..." Do you have any error message or at least some hint about the crash? SQLite manage transactions, so even in case of concurrent access the database should stay safe. However it manages transactions not directly, but through operating system primitives, so there could be problems from that side.

Comment: Here is one of the errors occurs: `W/SQLiteConnectionPool﹕ A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+data+com_app+databases+db.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.`      An other error seems like `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: error code 5: database is locked``

Comment: It seems that the problem is on the Java side: try to close every (result set/statement/connection) that you have opened, or edit your question to show the Java code so that someone can help you.